# Hide bottom HTML/widget, and remove Drag & Drop from Streamlit file_uploader()

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, streamlit

I´ve created an app using Streamlit, which needs to read multiple files at once. I´m using the `file_uploader()` component with the parameter `accept_multiple_files=True`.

I got 2 questions:

- First is if there´s a way to hide the bottom HTML/Widget that appears after uploading a file/s (see picture below)?
- And second, if there´s a way to remove the drag&drop option, just leaving "Browse Files" toggle button?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution currently is using the `st.beta_expander()` to hide the `st.file_uploader()` without having to programmatically play with the rerunning script to see if files were added. So for example in my problem it would be something like:

```
with st.beta_expander("Upload DICOM Files"):
    uploaded_files = st.file_uploader("Select DICOM Files:", 
                                      accept_multiple_files=True,
                                      type='dcm')
```

More info about the `st.beta_expander()` and what can be done with it **[here](https://docs.streamlit.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=expander#streamlit.beta_expander)**.